# Evitar que explorador guarde contraseña

Tags: html, asp.net

Holas....

He estado en búsqueda de una solución para evitar que el explorador ya se Chrome u otro, guarde en forma automática la contraseña, autocomple=off no funciona y otros, por ahora para evitar esto, el campo contraseña lo coloco en un campo texto tenue para que el explorador no reconozca los caracteres **** que es una contraseña y la guarde.

Esto lo necesito debido que la aplicación se levanta en un table con múltiples user por lo tanto no puedo dejar que guarde las contraseña y son varios Tablet.

Necesito conocer la forma de burlar esta situación.

Gracias...

Comment: El navegador hace lo que al navegador le sale de su programación de navegador. Como programador puedes *sugerirle* al navegador que no la guarde (y recalco lo de sugerir, porque no hay manera de impedir que una extensión de gestor de contraseñas guarde la misma por ejemplo). Si lo que quieres es simplemente deshabilitar el autocomplete puedes usar `autocomplete="new-password"` que lo deshabilita en la mayoría de navegadores actuales. Esto lo puedes ver con una simple búsqueda en google por cierto... sabías que investigar es necesario antes de preguntar?? [ask], [tour], lecturas recomendadas :)

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: los problemas de este tipo se suelen solucionar añadiendo una verificacion en dos pasos. tus usuarios tendrian un dispositivo (su movil, por ej) con un validador, y tu app, despues de pedir el user/pass, pediria el codigo correspondiente.